# source folders not visible in Netbeans project after installing jRebel plugin?

Tags: java, netbeans, jrebel

I installed jRebel on Netbeans 7.4 beta one day, the next day all my source folders an libraries to disappeared from my projects - except Maven ones. Like this:

[image]

The source folders are still present on my drive:

[image]

I just need to restore their visibility in my opened Netbeans projects.

When I try to add source packages from the "Properties" menu of the project, I do get the source back but as folders, not packages.

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Try going to `Files` view in Neteans, and look under the `src` folder in your project. Does the `src` folder have a sub-folder named `java`?

If not, create it (right click on `src`, go to `New`, select `Folder`). Your source packages should re-appear in the project view.

Comment: Upvoted as this helped me but in Maven projects the **java** subdir is under **src/main**

Answer (score 2):

This is for Netbeans 8.0. I am not sure if it is available for other versions.

Right click on the project -> Set Configuration -> Customize -> Sources -> Add Folder for Sources Packages Folder -> Select folders you want to see under your project -> OK

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans version 8:

In files tab, go to `main` folder and create a folder called `java`. That's it!