# Why is the build directory hidden in the projects view in an Netbeans 8.2 node.js application

Tags: node.js, netbeans-8

I have opened a working node.js application as a node.js project in Netbeans 8.2. Why is the build directory hidden? I can see it in files view, but I would prefer to see it with all the other directories. I have checked Options->Miscellaneous->Files->Files ignored by the IDE and build is not in the regular expression. How can I display the build directory in the projects view? If I embed the node.js application as a folder in a PHP project, there is no problem; the build folder is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Originally from a non-related [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869423/source-folders-not-visible-in-netbeans-project-after-installing-jrebel-plugin):

> This is for Netbeans 8.0. I am not sure if it is available for other
>   versions.
>
> Right click on the project -> Set Configuration -> Customize ->
>   Sources -> Add Folder for Sources Packages Folder -> Select folders
>   you want to see under your project -> OK

Comment: I'm working in Netbeans 8.2 and I can't find a "Set Configuration" item on the context menu.